# Bluetooth USB Dongle reconized as USB Mass Storage

Tags: bluetooth, usb, dongle

## Bluetooth dongle reconized as USB Mass Storage and Removable Disk

hello everyone. my USB Bluetooth dongle reconized as a USB mass storage and i cant use bluetooth. whats problem?? i think partition table corruptted or mainboard or NAND USB, etc...
when i open inside USB Bluetooth dongle it show 3 tracks un-playable file **.mp3**
all my drivers is up-to-date and everthing are alright.
[bluetooth dongle model:BTMR-6314](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4HEQ.png)
**i followed serveral solution but did not work**
*+ *tested by 2 systems but still same problem*

- *all my drivers is up-to-date*
- *cleaned & fixed all registry via CCleaner**
  = **i asked in Hidden Anonymous Forum too and even Sinister Witch King Hacker "Answer_Me_Now community telegram group doesnt helped yet. **

Comment: This question is not about programming and therefore off topic here. I assume you are using Windows, therefore the [SuperUser StackExchange](https://superuser.com/) would be a fit I believe